# Checking integrality of rings locally

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

All the rings considered in this post are commutative with 1. Suppose that $A\subseteq B$ are two rings ($A$ is a subring of $B$). The usual definition of integrality is as follows:

**Definition**. We say that $B$ is **integral** over $A$ if for every $b\in B$, there exists a *monic* polynomial $f\in A[x]$ such that $f(b)=0$.

Now, let's define another notion of "integrality".

**Definition**. We say that $B$ is **(locally) integral** over $A$ if for every $b\in B$ and for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq B$, the element $\overline{b}\in B/\mathfrak{q}$ is algebraic over the field $\operatorname{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})$ where $\mathfrak{p}:=A\cap\mathfrak{q}$ is the prime ideal of $A$.

It is clear that integral $\Rightarrow$ (locally) integral. My question is whether or not the converse holds:

> If $B$ is (locally) integral over $A$, then is $B$ integral over $A$?

Comment: What if $B$ is the field of fractions of $A$?

Comment: Great! So we get a counter-example by letting $A$ to be any integral domain which is **not** integrally closed, and letting $B=\operatorname{Frac}(A)$. Thanks! (Feel free to post your comment as an answer, since it fully answers the question)

Comment: As a remark: you don't need to take a non-integrally closed $A$ for the fraction field to be a counterexample. For example: $A = \Bbb Z$ and $B = \Bbb Q$. Then $B$ is certainly locally integral over $A$ and $A$ is integrally closed in $B$, but there is no monic $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $f(1/2) = 0$.